# How this program implements the concept of abstraction?

Tags: c++, abstraction

Today,i was searching about abstraction and i got this example....how this program implements the concept of abstraction and please also elaborate what is abstraction in c++

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Adder{
   public:
      // constructor
      Adder(int i = 0)
  {
    total = i;
  }
  // interface to outside world
  void addNum(int number)
  {
      total += number;
  }
  // interface to outside world
  int getTotal()
  {
      return total;
  };
  private:
  // hidden data from outside world
  int total;
};
int main( )
{
Adder a;

a.addNum(10);
a.addNum(20);
a.addNum(30);

cout << "Total " << a.getTotal() <<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You found a program that claimed to implement the "concept of abstraction" and that didn't say anything about it? Where did you find it? How do you know it does implement the "concept of abstraction" if that was not mentioned in the first place?

Comment: here is the source [link]http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_abstraction.htm[link]

Comment: It looks like there's a whole section of text before the example. What information do you miss or not understand?

Comment: i am not able to differentiate between data abstraction and data encapsulation ,both are looking same.

Comment: @vikJ: There's nothing relating the two. Read the material again.

Comment: @vikJ: Then [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_encapsulation.htm) from the very same web page may help

Answer (score 1):

It should be called [data abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29#Data_abstraction), which is the key source of OOP(not limited to C++).

Quoted from wikipedia:

> Data abstraction enforces a clear separation between the abstract
>   properties of a data type and the concrete details of its
>   implementation.

In your example, `Adder` is a data abstraction of an adder, which has two interfaces: `addNum` and `getTotal`. This abstraction hides(or encapsulates) the private data(`total` in this case), only expose its kernel behavior: adding a number and returning the current sum.

Comment: ok....i got it noww.....thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the `public` methods for doing your tasks without knowing how the `private members` are affected. this is nothing but `abstraction` .

You are moving your hand without knowing how your mind instruct it to move.

`Data Abstraction` : Hiding unnecessary details . in your case you hide how the `total` is calculated. you just call the function and your task is done.

`Data Encapsulation`: Binding `data` with `object`. In your case you binded the `total` with `object a`. so it's not accessible without `a` permission.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the constructor and function prototypes only:

```
class Adder {
  Adder(int i);
  void AddNum(int num);
  int getTotal();
};
```

The implementation is hidden, abstracted away, and only the prototypes remain.